# Modify/rewrite directed graph with an extra node

Tags: matlab, graph

If this is not the right forum to post this question on Graph theory please suggest the right forum.

I have a directed graph G with nodes 1, 2, 3,4. The adjacency matrix of G is

```
0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

I would like to redraw/modify G by adding a relay/ extra node (Node: 5) such that the edges in G are still maintained but are now routed/channelled through the relay/extra node. That is, the nodes in the new graph are now: 1,2,3,4, 5 and the adjacency matrix of the new graph might look like:

```
0 1 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 2 0
```

I am a newbie to graph theory, so I am not sure if this is the correct way of rewriting a graph. If yes, how to check that the original graph's links/connections are still maintained when using Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat difficult to answer. You want to add a node to a graph which removes and adds connections in some mysterious way? There are multiple ways to do this. If you are having trouble visualizing the edges of your graph, try using `sparse(adjMatrix)`- this will list your matrix in terms of its edges only.